# External autodiscover not required?

Tags: exchange

By now I have come across several environments where Outlook clients are used externally (over regular internet) but where the autodiscover service is not published externally.

I was always convinced that it is a requirement to publish autodiscover externally if you want to use Outlook externally but it seems I was wrong. You cannot create a new profile externally of course but when a client is configured internally and then goes out into the wild world of the public internet then it seems that Outlook continues to work perfectly (as long as you other services like Outlook Anywhere and webservices are configured correctly).

Are there services that should break when autodiscover is not available? For instance, would opening a calendar of another user work?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Autodiscover is cached and will be used if a current discovery is not available. Autodiscover is required for the proper operation of some Exchange features like the offline address book and out of office replies. It should be setup both internally and externally. That is according to Microsoft. Not just an opinion.

Comment: Hi Appleoddity, is it me or did some comments get removed from this thread? In any case, it seems that there is no absolute need to deploy autodiscover. Everything will work (including OAB and OOF) except configuring a new profile or adding an account.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it confirmed several times by now it seems that there is no absolute need to deploy autodiscover externally. Everything will work (including OAB and OOF) except configuring a new profile or adding an account. As long as you have internal autodiscover working and you setup your profiles internally, you should have no further issues.

That said, it's still recommended to set it up and I don't know of any good reasons not to do it.